# Is there any way to increase the impedance of a piezo element?

Tags: piezo

I'm trying to make a similar earpiece as the old crystal earpieces, that were made of a piezo element. I think they had about 20 kΩ impedance. I bought some piezo elements but I never found any with that high an impedance, just around 350 Ω. Is there any way to increase the impedance, without using a transformer?

Comment: Use a buffer amplifier or, if you are only interested in one spot frequency, design a passive impedance matcher (tricky of course).

Comment: ment for a crystal radio, so no power source added is my goal

Comment: A transformer is your only option but it will be tricky.

Comment: "old" crystal earpieces still are a thing you can buy. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071JWPTT9/

Comment: 19.65 k resistor in series?

Comment: solomon slow:yes i know i can buy them but, interested in try make them. Winny: no that not works, just for dc resistance.

Comment: I think its internal capacitans decides what impedance it has. Not so much knowing about impedance sadly but, just a guess.

Comment: Andy: i thjink so to.

Comment: @mathias The 2k Ohm earpieces sold by Radio Shack (back when I was playing more with crystal radios 4-5 decades ago) had extremely thin steel diaphragms that covered a cylindrical magnet and electromagnet coil. These were "pretty good." I didn't like the piezo ceramics as much.

Comment: @mathias I built my own magnet+steel diaphragm types, for practice. And I also built another based on the old Nathaniel Baldwin type c design using a balanced armature and either a metal or mica diaphragm (I tried both.) Mica can be flaked very thin and low mass. Impedance would be a little higher 6-10k Ohm. Regardless, you can and should make your own. The experience is worth the trouble. These [Brush](https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/brush_crystal_headphones.html) headphones were *much* higher impedance and good.

Comment: A "piezo element" is basically just a capacitor. As such, it has essentially infinite impedance at DC, and very high impedance at audio frequencies. This is what makes it a good match for an unpowered "crystal" radio. If you measured 350Ω, then what you bought was something else altogether.

Comment: @Dave Tweed. When i bougth them, the info told me they had 350 ohm impedance, and the most of them i could buy seem have about same impedance up to 2k i could see a few of them had. I allso tried this in another radio i made that needs high impedance earpiece, and compared the sound level with a "real" crystal earpiece, and it was llot lower. This is the one i bougth: https://www.electrokit.com/en/product/piezo-element-o20mm-7bb-20-6/

Comment: @jonk ok thanks for advice. Yeah the piezo earpiece do not have so good sound quality compared to a magnetic one i guess. I just wanted to make these piezo earpieces for fun,  3d print the earpiece and put a piezo element inside it. It works good then, just allot lower sound with this on 350 ohms then the original ones.

Comment: That isn't the kind of piezo used in an earpiece -- what you bought is meant for relatively higher-power applications. You want the kind linked by @SolomonSlow above -- it has a very thin and light piezo bar coupled to a similarly thin and light aluminum diaphragm, which makes it sensitive enough to use with your crystal radio. It also has a lower "Q", which gives it a better (but still not great) frequency response in the audio range.

Comment: @Dave Tweed yes i know that. But it seem impossible to find such thinner piezo elements. If you know any place where to buy them i am glad to here about it. The price for this ready made earpieces, i think is way to expensive. I have a few of them allready, and 1 broken i have inspected the element from. But for fun i would like to make them cheaper with a 3d printer and the element...if i just could find the element i need for it. This piezo i bougth works very ok in a printed shell, loud and clear sound on other radios that dont need that high impedance as a crystal radio.

Comment: Or maybe more fun try make the piezo element instead, with sodium potassium tartrate:)